# Why can't I have a Q_PROPERTY with this signature?

Tags: c++, qt, properties, metadata, qobject

I am new to the QT Property system, and am trying to understand why if I register and use properties in one way, it works, but in the other it fails.

I have two classes (`A` and `B`) that both inherit from `QObject`. Class `B` contains several instances of class `A` that I would like to register with the `Q_PROPERTY` macro.

Class A:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QMetaType>

class A: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(double X MEMBER X)
    Q_PROPERTY(double Y MEMBER Y)
    Q_PROPERTY(double Z MEMBER Z)

public:
    A() {    
        X = 0;
        Y = 0;
        Z = 0;
    }

    A(const A& other) {
        X = other.X;
        Y = other.Y;
        Z = other.Z;
    }

    A(double x, double y, double z) {
        X = x;
        Y= y;
        Z = z;
    }

    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;

    void operator =(const A& a) {
        X = a.X;
        Y = a.Y;
        Z = a.Z;
    }

    bool operator !=(const A& a) {
        return X != a.X || Y != a.Y || Z != a.Z:
    }
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(A)
```

If I declare Class B as follows, it works fine, despite the fact that I haven't done `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` for the pointer:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QMetaType>
#include "a.h"

class B : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(A* A1 READ getA1 WRITE setA1)
    Q_PROPERTY(A* A2 READ getA2 WRITE setA2)

public:
    static A A1;
    static A A2;

    B();
    B(const B& other);
private:

    A* getA1 (){
        return &A1;
    }

    void setA1(A* other){
        A1= *other;
    }

    A* getA2 (){
        return &A2;
    }

    void setA2(A* other){
        A2= *other;
    }
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(B)
```

However, if I declare B like this, it fails when I try to use the properties, saying A is an unregistered type:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QMetaType>
#include "a.h"

class B : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(A A1 MEMBER A1)
    Q_PROPERTY(A A2 MEMBER A2)

public:
    static A A1;
    static A A2;

    B();
    B(const B& other);
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(B)
```

Additionally I have called `qRegisterMetaType<A>()` and `qRegisterMetaType<B>()` at the top of my code.

This is how I am trying to use the properties of B:

```
//call this function with a B* as one parameter, a populated Json object as the other 
bool FromJson(QObject *o, const QJsonObject &obj){
    bool rtn = true;

    auto mo = o->metaObject();
    for (int i = mo->propertyOffset(); i < mo->propertyCount(); ++i){
        if(!mo->property(i).isConstant()){
            if(obj.contains(mo->property(i).name())){
                if(mo->property(i).type() == QVariant::UserType) {
                    //property is an A, go deeper
                    QVariant qobj = o->property(mo->property(i).name());
                    QObject* obj_ptr = qvariant_cast<QObject*>(qobj);

                    rtn = FromJson(obj_ptr, obj[mo->property(i).name()].toObject());
                }
                else {
                    //property is A.X, A.Y, A.Z
                    rtn = o->setProperty(mo->property(i).name(), obj[mo->property(i).name()]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

I would expect it to fail  on the line that casts the QVariant to a QObject*, but it actually fails on the previous line where it tries to get the property as a QVariant, saying that it is "unable to handle unregistered type A". Whereas it works peachy if B's properties are A*.

I feel like I'm missing something really dumb. Why can't I get back a valid QVariant unless B's properties are pointers?

Comment: You don't need to declare your object type to just use a pointer to it... after all it's just a pointer.  OTOH in the shorter `B` version you're using an actual object `A` as the property type (not ptr or ref), so Qt needs to know more about it.  I'm not sure why it is failing in your example once registered though, there must be some other bug.  You may need to provide a bigger sample of code (but simplify the actual failure point).  Also did you try with an access function for `B:A1` (like in first version) instead of relying on direct access?

Answer (score 0):

The `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(A)` can not be in the cpp file of the A class, it must be in the header file of this A class.  Same for class B.